# Getting Error while doing Sign In using custom policy in Azure Active Directory B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am struggling at the Sign-In functionality of an existing user in Azure Active Directory B2C. I had followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom) for implementing the custom claims in JWT token using custom policies. After modifying the `TrustFrameworkBase.xml`, `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml` & `SignUpOrSignin.xml` file as per my need by following the same link, I uploaded those files on azure and was trying to run user flow from the azure. Now the issue I am facing currently is that Sign-In functionality is not working. It is giving me the error **Unable to validate the information provided. (See the screenshot attached)**

Don't know where I am doing wrong.

Any help in this regard would be really helpful.

[image]

**Update:** After adding the Application Insights in my `SignUpOrSignIn.xml` file, Now I am able to get the exact error i.e **The claim type "objectId", designated as the identifier claim type, could not be found in the claims collection for the claims principal in tenant id "B2C_1A_signup_signin"**.
But don't know at which step I am missing it or how to modify the policy to run it successfully.

Comment: I had the same “Unable to validate the information provided” error, when tried to include my AppInsights-xxx profile  to ValidationTechnicalProfiles of parent profile https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/118000#issuecomment-1858517996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling to find the solution of the problem mentioned from 3 days, finally I was able to solve the problem.

I removed the tag
`<ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId" />` mentioned under `Technical Profile` tag with Id **SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email** in `TrustFrameworkBase.xml` file. Now I am able to subsequently sign in using ADB2C.

Comment: At first, did you create a b2c account or just try to login ? you firs tneed to create an account inside the tenant

Comment: Hi Thomas. Well I created the account using the signup flow from the app itself. But after signing up it was throwing the error during sign in.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava was this line being referenced somewhere down the base? If so, where exactly? I'm facing a similar issue but as the line in your answer is not being referenced anywhere on my policy set I believe it won't fix my issue.